# Replace words in string2 with string1 in C#

Tags: c#

Lets say I have two strings. `String1`  contains a string with correct spellings and `String2` contains a string with some mistakes.

```
string String1 = "This city is very beautiful"; 

string String2 = "The citi is very beautyful - and its also very big:";
```

Because `String1` contains the string with correct spellings. I want to replace the words in `String2` with `String1`, so at the end I should have.

```
String2 = "This city is very beautiful - and its also very big:";
```

The sentence will always be the same in both strings with the possibility of spelling mistakes in `String2`.

Comment: does string 2 always have typo's? and is there always a dash `-` to separate the sentences?

Comment: how do you understand that a given string contains a word with *non* correct spelling ?

Comment: @Tigran I made a function which is using Levenstein Distance for each word in String2 and puts the corrects words in String1.

Comment: @JPHellemons No, - is not always be included in String2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one compares each individual word, assuming the correct order, and that if string2 is longer, the rest of string2 will be appended.

Am sure it could be made more efficient (especially on long string, use stringbuilder etc).

**Edit:** Updated without foreach

```
        string s1 = "This city is very beautiful";
        string s2 = "The citi is very beautyful - and its also very big:";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s2) && s2.Contains(' '))
        {
            string[] partsS1 = s1.Split(' ');
            string[] partsS2 = s2.Split(' ');
            int count = partsS1.Length;
            for (int a = 0; a < count; a++)
            {
                if (partsS2.Length > count)
                {
                    if (partsS1[a] != partsS2[a])
                    {
                        partsS2[a] = partsS1[a];
                    }
                }
            }
            string final = string.Empty;
            foreach (string s in partsS2)
            {
                final += s + " ";
            }
            final = final.TrimEnd(' ');
            Console.WriteLine(final);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is based on your question:

```
String2 = String2.Replace("The citi is very beautyful", String1);

// You can also do it this way
String2 = String2.Replace("The citi is very beautyful", "This city is very beautiful");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like a spelling corrector.

[Check this code](http://frederictorres.blogspot.de/2011/04/how-to-write-spelling-corrector-from.html)